# How to override a static method with giving a different type

Tags: typescript

I've a class (`Foo`) and a subclass (`Bar extends Foo`) that both a static member function (`func(...)`) that have different type.

```js
interface IFoo {
  f1: string;
  f2: string;
}

class Foo {
  static func(data: Partial<IFoo>): Partial<IFoo> {
    return { f1: data.f1, f2: data.f2 }
  };
}

interface IBar extends Partial<IFoo>{
  b1: string;
  b2: string;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static func(data: Partial<IBar>): Partial<IBar> {
    return { ...Foo.func(data), b1: data.b1, b2: data.b2 }
  };
}
```

With this example, everything seems ok, but I need a second version of the `func` static method without the `Partial` type modifier :

```js
interface IFoo {
  f1: string
  f2: string
}

class Foo {
  static func(data: Partial<IFoo>): Partial<IFoo> {
    return { f1: data.f1, f2: data.f2 }
  };

  static func2 = Foo.func as (data: IFoo) => IFoo; // This one
}

interface IBar extends Partial<IFoo>{
  b1: string;
  b2: string;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static func(data: Partial<IBar>): Partial<IBar> {
    return { ...Foo.func(data), b1: data.b1, b2: data.b2 }
  };

  static func2 = Bar.func as (data: IBar) => IBar; // This one
}
```

Err... `func` and `func2` technically does the same thing, excepts `func` allows to have incomplete object argument, conversely to `func2` which needs a fully populated argument.

But I got this error on the "Bar" class :

```
Class static side 'typeof Bar' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Foo'.
  Types of property 'func2' are incompatible.
    Type '(data: IBar) => IBar' is not assignable to type '(data: IFoo) => IFoo'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
        Type 'IFoo' is missing the following properties from type 'IBar': b1, b2ts(2417)
```

Since `func` and `func2` are the same method, but just with a `Partial` modifier, is there any way to get rid of this error and be able to override `func2` correctly ?

=====

Edit :

@jcalz solutions are both fine, but if `Foo` is an abstract class, I got the following error :

```
Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type '(new () => Foo) & Pick<typeof Foo, "prototype" | "func">'.
  Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'new () => Foo'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts(2322)
```

Code :

```
const FooWithoutFunc2: (new () => Foo) & Omit<typeof Foo, "func2"> = Foo;

class Bar extends FooWithoutFunc2 {
  // ...
}
```

I presume I can't type Foo with `(new () => Foo)` since it's not *newable*... How can I type such an abstract `FooWithoutFunc2` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you override something, it needs to stay compatible with the thing you're overriding.  In TypeScript this is enforced on the static side of the class as well as the instance side of the class.  That means someone should be able to call `Bar.func2()` the same way they can call `Foo.func2()`. But you can't call `Bar.func2({f1: "", f2: ""})` in your definition, so the static side of `Bar` is not properly extending the static side of `Foo`.

So, possible fixes:

---

Maybe it's okay if someone calls `Bar.func2({f1: "", f2: ""})` and gets back `{f1: "", f2: "", b1: undefined, b2: undefined}`.  If I ask for `Foo.func2`, and you hand me `Bar.func2`, and I call it like I'd call `Foo.func2`, I get an output with these undefined extra properties, but the result is still a valid `IFoo`, so I should be happy (or at least it obeys the signature).  That means `Bar.func2` is both a valid `(x: IBar)=>IBar` and a valid `(x: IFoo)=>IFoo`.  So we can declare it to be both of them using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), which is equivalent to saying that `Bar.func2` has two [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) call signatures:

```
  class Bar extends Foo {
    static func(data: Partial<IBar>): Partial<IBar> {
      return { ...Foo.func(data), b1: data.b1, b2: data.b2 };
    }
    static func2 = Bar.func as ((data: IBar) => IBar) & typeof Foo.func2; // okay
  }

  Foo.func2({ f1: "", f2: "" });
  Bar.func2({ f1: "", f2: "", b1: "", b2: "" });
  Bar.func2({ f1: "", f2: "" }); // also okay because Bar.func2 extends Foo.func2
  const foo: Foo = new Bar(); // but Bar still extends Foo (the instance side)
```

---

Or, maybe you really don't want anyone to ever call `Bar.func2()` with something that isn't an `IBar` parameter.  In that case, it just cannot be true that `class Bar extends Foo`.  The instance side of `Bar` extends the instance side of `Foo`, but the constructor object itself does not.  We can express that also, by making another constructor object which makes `Foo` instances but isn't known by the compiler to have a `func2` static method:

```
  const FooWithoutFunc2: (new () => Foo) & Omit<typeof Foo, "func2"> = Foo;
  class Bar extends FooWithoutFunc2 {
    static func(data: Partial<IBar>): Partial<IBar> {
      return { ...Foo.func(data), b1: data.b1, b2: data.b2 };
    }
    static func2 = Bar.func as ((data: IBar) => IBar); // okay
  }

  Foo.func2({ f1: "", f2: "" });
  Bar.func2({ f1: "", f2: "", b1: "", b2: "" });
  Bar.func2({ f1: "", f2: "" }); // error, typeof Bar doesn't extend typeof Foo anymore
  const foo: Foo = new Bar(); // but Bar still extends Foo (the instance side)
```

Now `Bar` still extends `Foo` on the instance side, but `Bar` extends `FooWithoutFunc2` on the static side.

---

I guess it depends on your use case whether either of those works for you.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMsjAIwBcyAzmFKAOYDcRJMATFbfSM0QL5EiCADZxq1ZFhwFiyULTggkABSiYADlzqNkAXmQAiABYBbU4abIhcxWGAJSAV2UAKACZwwcKirhR7OBEAHgxsAD4ASl9-QJCwzHC8VhJkKAgwJygQPFJKZE9vADpyABpSTgKvOBL2ZH4WOUFCFLsHZ2U6g2kSl0dxZA9qqgTI-SSEqwB6KeQAFWNgSUwQCAEbUEhYRBRUACF-ZAgAD0gQd0k-AOAg0Okk2RIAI3zuRkbnyrfeRuaiEDgpgg1A0O2QAHkAG7QESYODuZJyUTiSQHKBHU4Qc6SaSI1I0bz2RwwPpDbwxa63fb+KIUuKhNEPFL49KZbK5IqcnoktyFOCRcovKh8oovQWVEVPOoNZn1WVtYl9LrING9ZTIAauMk+NBosZ6CZ65AAMmQYAAnhoIJgYFJsGqEOxprNMABrODmlJ-OTcpWuXB5KiGQzlDhBwz1SIfFX+B3sf2BowhirhwX5YPi8OR6OqnmOhPkVMppPZ5AzDUiag4N0e5BPCAIOBOagoXNKjFnC52zBxlIIFa0UjYKi4gyrADuMagrijZdmTycYCnBOAIhEHaxXdxrjAxhQCm8yhQ1GA7ggkXWLUIAKBILBAHVT1iAMIDuhOBBgTDox7IfsgQdpEfXdMEXdAlSoVwJ0GfUkmkMZTXBUxgDAYILStG1u3KQw83YQwkm6bBo2RCRlxOTscWwYDjFAsBwM6PFUgVDoEG1OkbniRlomQK56WpKAmTkFkMiyHIA05IpfV5aoBTrfJJTITMqmKKV6mjEhvXxZjcP0KcHQ1SQtT5EYjQNXV-Fncsa09JobBIKT8wDQsk1DSpg2zFI206At02TMMXLkospSzfgo082NcJ8ot-Pc0LnSOKB1Cgcp0OtW00QKTBgRAAByJdyM3M1LTS7sNRAc1TG-NYkTfIdMBHbBdOgtEZ3ihclwy2hV3XArsVKnc93kADDyQGgnwvQhmiAA)

Comment: Oh yes I better understand. It seems OK, but if `Foo` is an abstract class, I got the error ```Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type '(new () => Foo) & Pick<typeof Foo, "prototype" | "func">'.
  Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'new () => Foo'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts(2322)```

(I Edited the post the reflect this new problem)

Comment: Abstract classes are much harder to manipulate programmatically.  You can always assert your way out of the problem (e.g., `const FooWithoutFunc2 = Foo as unknown as (new () => Foo) & Omit<typeof Foo, "func2">;`) but that has other implications for any abstract methods and properties.  Honestly my suggestion is: don't use inheritance to represent things which don't inherit properly... move `func2` out of the class and keep it as a standalone function.  Good luck!